# Quicksort python implementation

Tags: python, quicksort

I am trying to write an implementation of quicksort where the pivot element is pseudo-random. I have looked at various posts online, many on SO but I am still having issues. Here is my code:

```
def quickSort(lst, a, b):
    if a < b:
        pivot = partition(lst, a, b)
        quickSort(lst, a, pivot-1)
        quickSort(lst, pivot+1, b)
    return lst



def partition(lst, a ,b):
    pivot = random.randint(a,b)
    for i in range(a,b):
        if lst[i] < lst[b]:
            lst[i],lst[pivot] = lst[pivot],lst[i]
            pivot += 1
    lst[pivot],lst[b] = lst[b],lst[pivot]
    return pivot
```

This code is practically identical to the code provided for the answer to this question: [quick sort python recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175380/quick-sort-python-recursion) but instead of using the `start` element as the pivot, I am using random. I keep getting this error:

```
 in partition
    lst[pivot],lst[b] = lst[b],lst[pivot]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have looked that up and I think it means that I am trying to reference an element of the list that doesn't exist or is out of the range of the list. Why is this happening?

I have also tried using the style of quicksort implemented in this link and I am getting the same error: [Quicksort implementation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634593/quicksort-implementation-in-python)

Comment: `random.randint` generates a random number from `[a, b]`. You probably need to substract 1 from `b` before passing it to `randint`.

Comment: @vaultah Just tried that. Got the exact same error

Comment: Well, if you just `print(len(lst), b, pivot)`, you should be able to see what the problem is

Comment: How are you calling `quicksort` initially? Specifically, what are you passing as `b`? If you use `len(lst)`, you'll get `IndexError`s, like you are now.

Comment: @Blckknght I am using `len(lst)-1` for `b` and `0` for `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what the `pivot` value in `partition` means. It's not the index of the element that's being partitioned around. Not until the end of the function anyway. The actual pivot value is `lst[b]`, the last element in the portion of the list being partitioned. That value gets moved to the `pivot` location on the next to last line of the function.

The `pivot` value is simply the index where the "high" values start. Picking a random initial value for `pivot` breaks the algorithm, since it may get incremented off the end of the list (consider what happens if `random.randint(a, b)` returns `b`).

If you want a random value to partition around, pick a random index and swap it's value with `lst[b]` before running the rest of the algorithm as normal (with the `pivot` index starting at `a`):

```
def partition(lst, a ,b):
    random_index = random.randint(a,b)  # pick random index, its value will be our pivot val
    lst[b], lst[random_index] = lst[random_index], lst[b]   # swap the value with lst[b]

    pivot = a        # run the rest of the partition code as it was in the original version
    for i in range(a,b):
        if lst[i] < lst[b]:
            lst[i],lst[pivot] = lst[pivot],lst[i]
            pivot += 1
    lst[pivot],lst[b] = lst[b],lst[pivot]
    return pivot
```

Comment: Ahhh I think I see what you mean. I can see now that within my for-loop `pivot` is getting incremented that's what's causing it to have an index error. Awesome!